# Interest rate models

Tags: interest-rates, data, market-data, historical-data

I'm studying by myself how to model interest rates. Is there any database in which I can find accurate data for indices like

- Libor,
- Euribor,
- Eonia
- etc?

Comment: I guess Bloomberg or Datastream may have them. What kind of model are you using?

Comment: I'm doing basic stuff with SABR

Comment: Rates won't be difficult to get. For example, LIBOR is readily available from FRED: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/USD3MTD156N. But it'll be challenging to get swaption quotes. I think you can get a small set from CME for free.

Answer (score 1):

Check out free daily interest rates at [ICE Benchmark Administration](https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/170)